# Box file service file actions

Tags: box-api

When building a File Service App, how can my app send data back to Box? I've been reading about the callback urls to send data to my app, but I don't see how my app can send data back that will update user's Box account, like there is with the Content API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token you get from Box in the callback is valid for you to call APIs.  Just use it in the header, and you'll be able to call APIs

Comment: Hmm, probably doesn't say it properly.  We'll be getting the v2 file-actions documentation up in the next few days, and I'll make sure we include it in there.